# Using name from list, for the name of a newly create a dataframe (using assign), but want to also use that name for the variable within

Tags: r

I'm creating a dataframe, naming the df with a name from a list using "assign". But I also want the column name /variable to have that same name. Here is example data

```
MEDIA <- c("TV", "Radio", "Cinema")
v1 <- 1:10
assign( MEDIA[1] , data.frame(  v1*2 )  )
get(MEDIA[1])
   v1...2
1       2
2       4
3       6
4       8
5      10
6      12
7      14
8      16
9      18
10     20
```

I created a df with name TV, but I want the variable within to also be named TV but using MEDIA[1] in the code, as I'm doing this in a "for loop".

I tried looking at it from this angle to create it within the assign, which works if you type the actual "TV" into it, but doesn't read MEDIA[1].

```
assign( MEDIA[1] , data.frame( TV = v1*2 )) # This works
assign( MEDIA[1] , data.frame( MEDIA[1] = v1*2 )) # This doesn't work
```

I've also tried to name the variable after creating the dataframe

```
names( TV ) <- MEDIA[1] # This works
names(MEDIA[1] ) <- MEDIA[1] # This doesn't work
```

Again using the "TV" works, but not when I use MEDIA[1].

Maybe there also a way to name the column/variable the same as the dataframe name?
If it helps there's only ever one single variable at a time.

I hope all that made sense. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this? It is never necessary to assign objects to symbols programmatically like this. This looks like a misuse of assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably better to put the created data frames in a list rather than having them floating around in workspace but to answer the question directly use setNames:

```
nm <- MEDIA[1]
assign(nm, setNames(data.frame(v1*2), nm))
```

This also works:

```
e <- .GlobalEnv
# e <- environment()   # use this if not in global env
nm <- MEDIA[1]
e[[nm]] <- data.frame(  v1*2 )
names(e[[nm]]) <- nm
```

To put them in a list:

```
L <- list()
nm <- MEDIA[1]
L[[nm]] <- setNames(data.frame( v1*2 ), nm)
```

It may be possible to create the list all once using Map if there exists a formula for creating the data frames.